# Is there any way that Simulink's 'goto' and 'from' tags could also be linked in the genearated html report

Tags: html, matlab, simulink, goto

I am working to generate an html report from a 'signal routing' Simulink Model (with Matlab 2012b). In Simulink, if I have appropriately declared the 'visibility tags', I can navigate through the model by double clicking on the 'goto' tag and clicking on the link which takes me to the corresponding 'from' tag. But the problem is that when I generate the html report, the 'goto' and 'from' in the html report are not linked i.e. I cannot reach to the respective 'from' tag by clicking on the 'goto' tag in the html page.

Is there any workaround on that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This question was flagged "unclear what you're asking". I think it is very clear but it might be only clear to few readers like me because I know all features you are using. To prevent this question from being closed I recommend to link both the blocks you are talking about and the report tool in your question.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Actually what I am trying to achieve is to be able to follow a signal path in the Simulink model I created. More specifically, I want to connect the output of my custom 'block 1' to input of my custom 'block 2' and follow the signal going on the link. Since my model is very complicated I have hundred of these custom blocks, I cannot connect all the blocks directly - it will render my model very messy and difficult to read.

Comment: The other way is to use Simulink's 'goto' tag with tag label of, for example, c100 and connect the tag to the output of my Simulink's 'block 1'.  Similarly, use a 'from' tag with same label i.e. c100 and connect it to the input port of the 'block 2. In Simulink, it works perfectly fine: I double click the 'goto' tag c100 and it shows me the link. When I click on that link , Simulink takes me to the corresponding 'from' tag c100 with the 'from ' tag being high-lighted in blue.

Comment: Now, the problem comes when I generate an HTML report from this Simulink model by clicking on File->Export->Web. In the generated HTML, the 'from' tag c100 cannot be traced by clicking on 'goto' tag c100.